# Can Metta Make you Beautiful?

Tags: metta-bhavana

Omg.Is this true.But what do you
mean like inner beauty? Or outer beauty? I'm more interested in outer beauty.Is there any reference in the suttas about being physically beautiful if you practice metta?

Thank you

Answer (score 5):

Metta **does** make you physicaly beautiful. You don't go from being super ugly, to super gorgeous. But it can improve a lot more than you might think.

Using an analogy, have you ever noticed that when you are in a realy good mood, people are more enthusiastic with you? And have you ever noticed how when you're in a bad mood, the opposite happens? We all react instinctively to other people's moods, because these moods are "written" in the facial expression, even if we're not consciously aware of "reading" these facial expressions. It's just how the human animal reacts through instinct.

Metta cultivates such high spirits of kindness, happiness and love that your facial expression becomes pleasant, loving and happy. The bitterness, anger, frustration, depression, etc, all melt, day by day, with he practice of metta. Through continued practice, that makes you more and more beautiful.

But if you don't believe me, check these photos taken before and after a meditation retreat:

http://www.shambhalamountain.org/dathun-before-and-after-photos/

Comment: Yeah your right! Somethings changed in the photos.

Comment: Apparently, metta also gives you access to a better photographer.

Comment: The photographer was the same. The practice in a Dhatun is about mindfulness, and not metta. And what you say would not invalidate in the least the fact that metta makes you happier and more loving. And that the facial expressions assossiated with these qualities are also assossiated with beauty.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the [Mettanisamsa Sutta](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/an/an11/an11.016.piya.html) lists eleven benefits of Metta meditation, out of which ten can be experienced in this life. The ninth one is the one related to this question: "His/her countenance is serene"

Also read the [Culla-kamma vibhanga sutta](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/mn/mn.135.nymo.html)

> "But here some woman or man is not angry or much given to rage; even
>   when much is said, he is not furious, angry, ill-disposed, resentful,
>   nor does he show ill-temper, hate or surliness. Due to having
>   performed and completed such kammas, on the dissolution of the body,
>   after death, he reappears in a happy destination... If instead he
>   comes to the human state, **he is beautiful wherever he is reborn**. This
>   is the way that leads to beauty, that is to say, not to be angry or
>   given to much rage; even when much is said, not to be furious, angry,
>   ill-disposed or resentful, or to show ill-temper, hate or surliness.

Comment: Hmm.." his her countenance is serene"..but that just means calm looking tho.

Comment: The alternate translation say [one's complexion is bright](http://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/an/an11/an11.016.than.html). Also look into the merits of giving alms food. One of the 5 benefits is having nice skin color. Also, there's a story about a girl offering flowers to the [Ruwanwelisaya](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruwanwelisaya) and wishing for beauty. As a result she was born so beautiful that even the kings fought for her. But later she got killed because of it.

Answer (score 2):

> 43. HOW TO OBTAIN WEALTH, BEAUTY, AND SOCIAL POSITION.
>
> Translated from the Anguttara-Nikâya (iv.1971).
>
> On a certain occasion The Blessed One was dwelling at Sâvatthi, in
>   Jetavana monastery in Anâthapindika's Park. Then drew near Mallikâ the
>   queen to where the Blessed One was; and having drawn near and greeted
>   The Blessed One, she sat down respectfully at one side. And seated
>   respectfully at one side, Mallikâ the queen spoke to The Blessed One
>   as follows:
>
> "Reverend Sir, what is the reason, and what is the cause, when a
>   woman is ugly, of a bad figure, and horrible to look at, and indigent,
>   poor, needy, and low in the social scale?
>
> "Reverend Sir, what is the reason, and what is the cause, when a
>   woman is ugly, of a bad figure, and horrible to look at, and rich,
>   wealthy, affluent, and high in the social scale?
>
> "Reverend Sir, what is the reason, and what is the cause,
>
> p. 229    [A.iv.1971 when a woman is beautiful, attractive, pleasing, and
>   possessed of surpassing loveliness, and indigent, poor, needy, and low
>   in the social scale?
>
> "Reverend Sir, what is the reason, and what is the cause, when a
>   woman is beautiful, attractive, pleasing, and possessed of surpassing
>   loveliness, and rich, wealthy, affluent, and high in the social
>   scale?"
>
> "Mallikâ, when a woman has been irascible and violent, and at every
>   little thing said against her has felt spiteful, angry, enraged, and
>   sulky, and manifested anger, hatred, and heart-burning; when she has
>   given no alms to monk or Brahman, of food, drink, building-sites,
>   carriages, garlands, scents, ointments, bedding, dwelling-houses, and
>   lamps, but has been of an envious disposition, and felt envy at the
>   gains, honor, reverence, respect, homage, and worship that came to
>   others, and been furious and envious thereat; then, when she leaves
>   that existence and comes to this one, wherever she may be born, she is
>   ugly, of a bad figure, and horrible to look at, and indigent, poor,
>   needy, and low in the social scale.
>
> "And, again, Mallikâ, when a woman has been irascible and violent,
>   and at every little thing said against her has felt spiteful, angry,
>   enraged, and sulky, and manifested anger, hatred, and heart-burning;
>   but has given alms to monks and Brahmans, of food, drink,
>   building-sites, carriages, garlands, scents, ointments, bedding,
>   dwelling-houses, and lamps, and has not been of an envious
>   disposition, nor felt envy at the gains, honor, reverence, respect,
>   homage, and worship that came to others, nor been furious and envious
>   thereat; then, when she leaves that existence and comes to this one,
>   wherever she may be born, she is ugly, of a bad figure, and horrible
>   to look at, and rich, wealthy, affluent, and high in the social scale.
>
> "And, again, Mallikâ, when a woman has not been irascible or
>   violent, and though much had been said against her, has not felt
>   spiteful, angry, enraged, or sulky, nor manifested anger, hatred, and
>   heart-burning; when she has given no alms to monk or Brahman, of food,
>   drink, building-sites, carriages, garlands, scents, ointments,
>   bedding, dwelling-houses,
>
> p. 230    [A.iv.1974 and lamps, but has been of an envious disposition,
>   and felt envy at the gains, honor, reverence, respect, homage, and
>   worship that came to others, and been furious and envious thereat;
>   then, when she leaves that existence and comes to this one wherever
>   she may be born, she is beautiful, attractive, pleasing, and possessed
>   of surpassing loveliness, and indigent, poor, needy, and low in the
>   social scale.
>
> "And, again, Mallikâ., when a woman has not been irascible or
>   violent, and though much had been said against her, has not felt
>   spiteful, angry, enraged, or sulky, nor manifested anger, hatred, and
>   heart-burning; when she has given alms to monks and Brahmans, of food,
>   drink, building-sites, carriages, garlands, scents, ointments,
>   bedding, dwelling-houses, and lamps, and has not been of an envious
>   disposition, nor felt envy at the gains, honor, reverence, respect,
>   homage, and worship that came to others, nor been furious and envious
>   thereat; then, when she leaves that existence and comes to this one,
>   wherever she may be born, she is beautiful, attractive, pleasing, and
>   possessed of surpassing loveliness, and rich, wealthy, affluent, and
>   high in the social scale.
>
> "This, Mallikâ, is the reason, this is the cause, when a woman is
>   ugly, of a bad figure, and horrible to look at, and indigent, poor,
>   needy, and low in the social scale.
>
> "This, Mallikâ, is the reason, this is the cause, when a woman is
>   ugly, of a bad figure, and horrible to look at, and rich, wealthy,
>   affluent, and high in the social scale.
>
> "This, Mallikâ, is the reason, this is the cause, when a woman is
>   beautiful, attractive, pleasing, and possessed of surpassing
>   loveliness, and indigent, poor, needy, and low in the social scale.
>
> "This, Mallikâ, is the reason, this is the cause, when a woman is
>   beautiful, attractive, pleasing, and possessed of surpassing
>   loveliness, and rich, wealthy, affluent, and high in the social
>   scale."
>
> When he had thus spoken, Mallikâ the queen replied to The Blessed
>   One as follows:
>
> "Since, now, Reverend Sir, in a former existence I was irascible
>   and violent, and at every little thing said against
>
> p. 231    [A.iv.1977 me felt spiteful, angry, enraged, and sulky, and
>   manifested anger, hatred, and heart-burning, therefore am I now ugly,
>   of a bad figure, and horrible to look at. Since, now, Reverend Sir, in
>   a former existence I gave alms to monks and Brahmans, of food, drink,
>   building-sites, carriages, garlands, scents, ointments, bedding,
>   dwelling-houses, and lamps, therefore am I now rich, wealthy, and
>   affluent. Since, now, Reverend Sir, in a former existence I was not of
>   an envious disposition, nor felt envy at the gains, honor, reverence,
>   respect, homage, and worship that came to others, nor was furious and
>   envious thereat, therefore am I now high in the social scale.
>
> "Now, in this royal family, Reverend Sir, there are maidens of the
>   warrior caste, maidens of the Brahman caste, and maidens of the
>   householder caste, and I bear rule over them. From this day forth I
>   will not be irascible nor violent, and, though much be said against
>   me, I will not feel spiteful, angry, enraged, or sulky, nor manifest
>   anger, hatred, and heart-burning; I will give alms to monks and
>   Brahmans, of food, drink, building-sites, carriages, garlands, scents,
>   ointments, bedding, dwelling-houses, and lamps; and I will not be of
>   an envious disposition, nor feel envy at the gains, honor, reverence,
>   respect, homage, and worship that shall come to others, nor be furious
>   and envious thereat.
>
> "O wonderful is it, Reverend Sir! O wonderful is it, Reverend Sir!
>   It is as if, Reverend Sir, one were to set up that which was
>   overturned; or were to disclose that which was hidden; or were to
>   point out the way to a lost traveller; or were to carry a lamp into a
>   dark place that they who had eyes might see forms. Even so has The
>   Blessed One expounded the Doctrine in many different ways. I betake
>   myself to The Blessed One for refuge, to the Doctrine, and to the
>   Congregation of the priests. Let The Blessed One receive me, who have
>   come to him for refuge, and accept me as a disciple from this day
>   forth as long as life shall last."

There's a few other sutras that mention this idea that when one is angry (emanating UGLY energy outwards) one will receive an ugly countenance (reflective UGLY energy back to one's persona).

Metta produces the opposite effect.
I know that my pictures tend to be the best when I am mentally doing metta (genuinely, not "trying").

Lastly, the benefits go far beyond improving one's physical countenance.

Comment: May I know how do u do Metta mentally? I'm not following, mind to enlighten me?

Comment: There are many guides, but the gist remains the same: start with yourself.
Once you feel very loved and full of love, you can share this quality with others (mentally).
Bless others with metta starting with close friends and companions and moving towards complete strangers and those who have done you harm.
When completed, rest in this love and move on to vipassana, the core practice of Buddhism.
Sometimes I rush and do this entire exercise in about 30 seconds, sometimes I take an hour, combining this with yoga at the beach, imagining myself as all-being as an all-thing..

Comment: Was just wondering, can one just skip all and go straight to the neutral party? Wouldn't the coverage be much more wider? It will probably goes like this, may all beings be happy, may all beings be peaceful.......Instead of starting with May I be happy, may I be peaceful...I suppose the "All" includes yourself too. Would it work?

Comment: Yes that is fine.
Feel free to start wherever you please but do try it the way the Buddha recommended once, setting aside a period of time to dwell on the love, making it as unconditional as possible.